# How do you use a block function/will_paginate in Rails to generate data into col-sm-4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= image_tag photo.picture.ad.url %>

<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @photos %> 


def index
  @photos = @user.photos.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 9)
end
```

I want to use the following layout, row -> col-sm-12 -> col-sm-4, with each photo being placed in a col-sm-4, three rows of three pictures, nine pictures per page, like instagram, I have tried many combinations of code but cannot get it to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<div class = "row">
  <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
    <div class = "col-sm-3"><%= image_tag photo.picture.ad.url %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @photos %> 


def index
  @photos = @user.photos.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 9)
end
```

Comment: this results in 9 rows with one photo in each row.

Comment: this works. mine below is a bit better because it creates three rows instead of only row. also, it should be col-sm-4.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I figured it out:

```
<% @photos.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% group.each do |photo| %>
      <div class = "col-sm-4">
        <%= image_tag(photo.picture.ad.url, class: "img-responsive") %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>  

<%= will_paginate @photos %> 

def index
  @photos = @user.photos.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 9)
end
```